# apt-get autoclean doesn't clean the deb files in /var/cache/apt/archives

Tags: apt

This command can't auto-clean these useless files, I have to remove them by myself, what can I do?

The result of my laptop:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Del firefox-locale-en 41.0.2+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [667 kB]
Del software-properties-common 0.92.37.5 [9,370 B]
Del youtube-dl 2015.10.06.2-1~webupd8~trusty1 [581 kB]
Del software-properties-gtk 0.92.37.5 [46.8 kB]
Del linux-libc-dev 3.13.0-66.108 [775 kB]
Del firefox-locale-zh-hant 41.0.2+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [452 kB]
Del python3-apport 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.16 [75.2 kB]
Del linux-signed-generic-lts-vivid 3.19.0.31.18 [1,830 B]
Del apport 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.16 [181 kB]
Del linux-signed-image-generic-lts-vivid 3.19.0.31.18 [2,300 B]
Del firefox 41.0.2+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [41.5 MB]
Del python3-software-properties 0.92.37.5 [19.1 kB]
Del linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid 3.19.0.31.18 [2,242 B]
Del python3-problem-report 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.16 [9,884 B]
```

The result of my PC:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

It doesn't make sense.

Maybe it's time to reinstall the system...and StackExchange sucks at supporting Chinese...

Comment: It will delete some .deb files not all. Don't you see atleast a few?

Comment: It doesn't clean anyone of them on my PC, but it works on my laptop, unless I clean them all by apt-get clean.

Comment: ok [edit] Q and  add output of `ls -l` in `cd /var/cache/apt/archives` __before and after__ running `sudo apt-get autoclean`

Comment: The result is written above.

Comment: Nice idea. I too currently needed count =)

Comment: Did you got any error message after executing `sudo apt-get autoclean`? Are you using `sudo`?

Comment: No, there is no error message.  Yes, I use sudo.

Comment: see my answer =)...are you getting same result as I posted in my answer(at the end) ?

Comment: Please let me  know regarding my answer @JulianLai :)

Comment: What do you mean by "supporting Chinese"? Well, will you please post output of `sudo apt-get auto remove` of lapy now? You will see same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any error in this question.

From manual of [apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man8/apt-get.8.html):

> **autoclean**:
>
> Like clean, autoclean clears out the local repository of retrieved
>              package files. The difference is that it only removes package files
>              that can no longer be downloaded, and are largely useless. This
>              allows a cache to be maintained over a long period without it
>              growing out of control. The configuration option
>              APT::Clean-Installed will prevent installed packages from being
>              erased if it is set to off.

It means `autoclean` never clean sweep ( I mean remove **all**) packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

In your case, there might be nothing to remove.

Take my case as example:

Output of `ls -l` in `/var/cache/archives`

Before execution of `sudo apt-get autoclean`

```
ravan@ravan:/var/cache/apt/archives$ ls -l
total 330584
```

After execution:

```
ravan@ravan:/var/cache/apt/archives$ ls -l
total 234852
```

Further more, if you execute the command you will get like this,

```
ravan@ravan:~$ sudo apt-get autoclean
[sudo] password for ravan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

Comment: My question have been edited, but I have changed my system, so I don't care about it anymore......I still appreciate for your help.